# How to find default value of Columns in Sybase ASE

Tags: sap-ase

We want to find the default value of a column in Sybase ASE. Similar Query for SQL server is given below and we want same for sybase.

```
SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: Copied from this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63677140/7366100):

---

How to find the default value in the Sybase ASE system tables ...

- If a column has a default value the associated record in *syscolumns*
  will have a non-zero value stored in the *cdefault* column, ie,
  ***syscolumns.cdefault > 0***.
- The non-zero *cdefault* value is a pointer to a record in *syscomments* where information about the default is stored, ie, ***syscolumns.cdefault = syscomments.id***.
- The actual default value is stored in the *syscomments.text* column in
  one of two formats depending on if the default was **a)** defined inline
  as part of a *create/alter table* command or **b)** defined as a standalone default via the *create default* command.

Example:

```
-- inline default value of '0' assigned to column 'b'
create table t1 (a int, b int default 0 not null, c int)
go

-- standalone default named 'myzero' with default value of '0'; bound to column 'c'
create default myzero as 0
go
sp_bindefault myzero, 't1.c'
go

sp_help t1
go
...
 Column_name ... Default_name
 ----------- ... --------------
 a           ... NULL          
 b           ... t1_b_467529718             -- inline default
 c           ... myzero                     -- standalone default
...

-- contents of syscolumns.cdefault
select name, cdefault from syscolumns where id = object_id('t1') order by colid
go
 name       cdefault
 ---------- -----------
 a                    0
 b            467529718
 c            387529433

-- contents of syscomments.text
select id,text from syscomments where id in (467529718,387529433) order by id
go
 id        text
 --------- ---------------------------
 467529718 DEFAULT  0                       -- inline default
 387529433 create default myzero as 0       -- standalone default

-- pulling this all together:

select col.name, com.text
from   syscolumns  col,
       syscomments com
where  col.id = object_id('t1')
and    col.cdefault = com.id
order by 1
go
 name       text
 ---------- ------------------------------
 b          DEFAULT  0                      -- inline default
 c          create default myzero as 0      -- standalone default
```

From here you should be able to parse out the default value based on the format of the *syscomments.text* column and the actual default value (ie, is it numeric? is it a character string, possibly with embedded space? is it a function reference, eg, *getdate()*).